# Can't find Google Chrome bookmarks after pc crash per recovered data?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Can somebody tell me where Chrome stores its bookmarks per windows7?  My PC crashed but I recovered the data but can't seem to locate my bookmarks locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default

Where username is your login name. There is a file called "Bookmarks" and a file called "bookmarks.bak"

You can also use:

> %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\